# Creating a Windows installer for Numeric python Inno setUp

Tags: numpy, registry, windows-installer, inno-setup

Is it possible to create a windows installer for **numeric python** using **inno setup** by looking in to registry values.I was able to create a similar one  for python , Is it possible to have a similar one which will install the numeric python packages by checking the registry.

Comment: It was discussed here few questions ago (but I can't find the question, since it might have been deleted). What I remember from that discussion is that NumPy has an NSIS installer, but can be "installed" manually and this means that you shouldn't expect that if you don't find registry values of that installer, that the NumPy is not installed. It can be, just manually. So you should consider to use except registry check also a check if the key module file exists and for sure add the selectable option for the user.

Comment: @TLama You mean I need to check the whole system for the key modules , or it can be found in some specific locations like along with the python files, or else in the program files? Please advise...